# Overlay of pdf using PairedHistogram in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

With a standard 1D histogram, I can generate a pdf overlay using `Show` and `Plot`.

I'd like to do something similar with `PairedHistogram`. I can't find any examples. I have tried 
using `Epilog`, but I can't figure out how to pass the graphics primitive correctly such that they are matched to the correct histogram.

I'd like to add overlays to the below, with an overlay specified for each histogram in the pair.

```
PairedHistogram[data[[18]],data[[22]],Automatic,"PDF",
   ChartStyle->{{LightOrange,LightBlue},None,None},
   ChartLegends->Placed[{names[[18]],names[[22]]},Top]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not beautiful, but you can use `ParametricPlot` adjusted by the `BarSpacing` to accomplish this.

```
With[{bs = .1}, 
    Show[PairedHistogram[
          RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100], 
          RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-3, 3}], 1000],
          Automatic, "PDF", ChartStyle -> {{LightOrange, LightBlue}, None, None}, 
          BarSpacing -> bs], 

         ParametricPlot[{PDF[UniformDistribution[{-3, 3}], t] + bs/2, t}, 
            {t, -3, 3}, Axes -> None], 
         ParametricPlot[{-PDF[NormalDistribution[], t] - bs/2, t}, 
            {t, -3, 3}, Axes -> None], PlotRange -> All]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!